# FInd the length of string values but not number values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to find the length of the the string value but also don't need to get the length of the number values.

How to fix this? This is my code:

```
def CalcStringlen(string):
    if type(string) == int:
        return("Sorry integers don't have length")
    else:
        return len(string)

string = input("Enter the string")
print(CalcStringlen(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast 

def CalcStringlen(string):
    if type(string) == int:
        return("Sorry integers don't have length")
    else:
        return len(string)

string = ast.literal_eval(input("Enter the string: "))
print(CalcStringlen(string))
```

Output:

```
Enter the string: 1234                                                                                                                         
Sorry integers don't have length
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` call is returning a string. Even if it only has numbers in it, it is still a string and its type will never be `int`. Change this test:

```
if type(string) == int:
```

to

```
if string.isdigit():
```